# Segue is not performed iOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, segue

I am using XCode 6, targeting iOS 8 and coding this in Swift.

My storyboard controllers look like this:

```
Tab Bar > Navigation > Table View > Detail View
```

The `Show Detail` segue is from a `Table Cell` to the `Detail View`.

The `prepareForSegue` method is not triggered when clicking a table cell. Segue from a button to detail works fine, though. `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` also works fine.

I have also created a brand new test project to test this issue - the controller code looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class TestTableController: UITableViewController
{
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cellId = "testCell";
        var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as? UITableViewCell;

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellId);
        }

        cell!.textLabel!.text = "cell \(indexPath.item)";

        return cell!;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this does not work out of the box?

P.S.: when using `Split View` instead of a `Tab Bar`, the same segue works fine.

Comment: Make sure you're running Xcode 6 / iOS 8.1 as I had numerous issues with segues (particularly unwind segues) in 8.0.x but they've all been fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it with a sample project. It works fine. There must be something wrong with your wiring up the cell.

Here is my code. Only indicating changes from plain vanilla tab bar project template.

[image]

```
// FirstViewController.swift
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let detail = segue.destinationViewController as DetailController
    let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    detail.detailItem = "Cell \(indexPath!.row + 1)"
}

//DetailController.swift
class DetailController: UIViewController {

    var detailItem : String!
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        label.text = detailItem
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I did... How does it look in the storyboard's XML? Are you running iOS 8.0 or 8.1? XCode 6.0 or the beta?

Comment: 6.0.1, 8.0. Did not peruse the XML - just did the obvious stuff.

Comment: I have deleted the cell's ID, set it again in IB to the same value and it started working (WTF?)...
Marked your answer as correct because you confirmed there is nothing wrong with my code and led me to mess with the cell.

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me when I was registering cell in ViewDidLoad method using `tableView.register(AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)`  When i commented this line and added the cell class and cell identifier in storyboard, it started working. Again if I uncomment that code in viewdidload, it stops working.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I was switching from a xib implementation to storyboards, and I was still using the custom cell's xib instead of having it defined as the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

for calling the method prepareForSegue you must have to add a segue to connect the prototype cell and the destination Controller! method doesn't called if you navigate to destination controller programmatically!

Comment: Actually, `prepareForSegue` does get called even if you `performSegue` programmatically. I want it to work without programmatically calling `performSegue`, as it should...